# Apache Syncope with OAuth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, identity, cas, apache-syncope

I am trying to find some information about using Apache syncope (Identity management system) with OAuth 2 authorization.

I see there is no implementation in AS yet as written here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SYNCOPE-534 so AS is "pure" Identity Manager - not directly involved in authorization operations like oauth 2.0

I have found I should use some Access Managers to implement such scenario.
What access managers should I use? Could you give some advice? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the page [Access Managers](http://syncope.apache.org/docs/reference-guide.html#access-managers) you can see that there exist several ones, just not for `OAuth 2`.
For `OAuth 2` an Access Manager had to be developed, perhaps it's possible on base of the existing ones.
Having a look at some commits concerning `OpenID` there exist the following list:

- [[SYNCOPE-1270] implementation for `OpenID` Connect for Admin Console and Enduser](https://github.com/apache/syncope/pull/74/commits/f29e60f62f12bc7ec77ce6de4d2674db466a8f4f)
- [[SYNCOPE-1270] `OpenID` Connect Logout implementation](https://github.com/apache/syncope/pull/75/commits/c0a3d367da4774d00c474b5cb7813f5c58414db3)
- [[SYNCOPE-1018] self registration for `OpenID` Connect](https://github.com/apache/syncope/pull/76/commits/e7d679512650e091a01fba19374f2149b8b19439)

It seems being mixed in core though, so probably it's impracticable to do it in the same kind as core can't be updated anymore without problems.
On the other hand, if you are willing to provide the new Access Manager directly to core-development it wouldn't matter, but then it's advisable to contact the core-developers on github first.

While [REST](http://syncope.apache.org/docs/reference-guide.html#rest) might serve as interface for a separated module, the authentication process is technically explained as `Provisioning Service`.

In [Extensions](http://syncope.apache.org/docs/reference-guide.html#extensions) you get an impression which extensions exist and you'd to verify them to get knowledge how to solve your approach in an own extension. I'd chose perhaps [SAML 2.0 Service Provider](http://syncope.apache.org/docs/reference-guide.html#saml-2-0-service-provider) as it's also related to authentication.

Concerning `OAuth 2` itself there exist a [few implementations in github](https://github.com/thephpleague/oauth2-client/search?l=PHP&q=oauth2), regrettable only in PHP, but perhaps that helps you a bit.